# Finding Audit Reports and Results for Whole Disk Encryption Solutions

Tags: audit, disk-encryption

Due to TrueCrypt being pulled from the web even though it's been audited, I was asked to compare the audit of TrueCrypt against audits and information available for other products that do whole disk encryption, including McAfee, Symantec, etc.

The problem is, I'm not sure if there were any audits performed on those products, nor am I sure where to find them.  Given that security is a paramount requirement at my workplace, does anyone know if any of the other major Whole Disk Encryption solutions (which ideally need to be cross platform) have publicly published the results of their audits?

The specific products I am supposed to start looking at for such information are as follows (to narrow the scope of the question):

- Symantec PGP Whole Disk Encryption
- McAfee Endpoint Encryption
- Built-in BitLocker (for Windows, as an option)

Comment: I guess it might be harder to find such audit on closed source system than it is on open sources ones. For your information, there has already been a post [comparing TrueCrypt with BitLocker](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85149/truecrypt-vs-bitlocker), I especially like the second answer actually proposing to use both...

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf thanks for the 'related link'.  Ultimately I need some kind of audit information or comparison information to present to management.  I was just tasked with the research and summarization, I don't make the call of what to use...